# Bug auto create linebreak on view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, checkbox, line-breaks

HTML views like this:

`□ホーチミン　□ハノイ　□フエ　□ホイアン　□その他`

I got a problem, the validate is you must select at least one checkbox, so if no checkbox be checked it will show an error

When I select some checkboxes, my view look fine and no problem

`☑ホーチミン　☑ハノイ　□フエ　□ホイアン　□その他`

But when I don't check any checkbox, my view will auto creates linebreak like this:

```
□
ホーチミン　
□
ハノイ　
□
フエ　
□
ホイアン　
□
その他
都市を選択してください
```

contact.rb:

```
validate :validate_city_ids
  serialize :city_ids

  def validate_city_ids
    unless city_ids
      errors.add(:city_ids, "都市を選択してください")
    end
  end
```

In this file above, if I remove line: errors.add(:city_ids, "都市を選択してください") of course if won't show error, in this statement, it don't auto creates linebreaks

My View looks like this:

```
<td>
        <%= f.check_box :city_ids, {multiple: true}, "1", nil %> <%= f.label :"ホーチミン" %> &nbsp;
        <%= f.check_box :city_ids, {multiple: true}, "2", nil %> <%= f.label :"ハノイ" %> &nbsp;
        <%= f.check_box :city_ids, {multiple: true}, "3", nil %> <%= f.label :"フエ" %> &nbsp;
        <%= f.check_box :city_ids, {multiple: true}, "5", nil %> <%= f.label :"ホイアン" %> &nbsp;
        <%= f.check_box :city_ids, {multiple: true}, "7", nil %> <%= f.label :"ニャチャン" %>
        <br/>
        <%= f.check_box :city_ids, {multiple: true}, "6", nil %> <%= f.label :"ムイネー" %> &nbsp;
        <%= f.check_box :city_ids, {multiple: true}, "11", nil %> <%= f.label :"その他" %> &nbsp;
        <br/>
        <% if @contact.errors[:city_ids].any? %>
          <span class="error-explain">
            <%= @contact.errors[:city_ids].first %>
          </span>
        <% end %>
      </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting the whole thing myself, this is the problem:

Rails puts the "fields_with_error" div around the checkbox. There are several possible ways to solve this, the most straightforward would be applying a css rule to "fields_with_error"

```
.field_with_errors {
    display: inline;
}
```

---

OR change the default behavior by adding this to config/application.rb

```
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance| 
  "#{html_tag}".html_safe 
}
```

This needs an application restart to take effect! It will wrap the fields_with_error div around label.

In any case change error-explain span to

```
<div class="error-explain">
  <%= @contact.errors[:email].first %>
</div>
```

Have fun ;)

NOTE: I used the following markup:

```
<label for="contact_ホーチミン">
  <%= f.check_box :city_ids, {multiple: true}, "1", nil %> ホーチミン &nbsp;
</label>
<label for="contact_ハノイ">
  <%= f.check_box :city_ids, {multiple: true}, "2", nil %> ハノイ &nbsp;
</label>
...
```

Comment: This is syntax error, because first %> will close <%=, so this code will has no effect...

Comment: I see, it's ugly anyway. You can try with normal <label> tags. (see edited answer)

Comment: Damn... Have you tryed floating with your original markup? in css: label{ float:left;} and input[type="checkbox"]{float: left;}

Comment: Yes, although I use label float:left but it still linebreaking every label and checkbox

Comment: Ok, I tried to replicate your issue, but I cant... No linebreaks for me. Please use FireBug or similar to check if there are any css rules on the line-break labels

Comment: Is that project hosted? Can I see it live?

Comment: https://github.com/YutoYasunaga/tnk-contact
Here is it, I'm very headache with this problem ...

Comment: It only get auto linebreak when I add this line to validate:
`errors.add(:city_ids, "都市を選択してください")`